# How can I make MODx manager UI work faster?

Tags: content-management-system, modx, modx-evolution

I am currently involve in developing projects on MODx Revolution. I like this system, it fast and great, but what really annoying is manager interface. It works really slow. Every single action require ExtJs panels refreshing. Is there any way to change this behavior or roll back to Evolution interface?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot change it (without modifying the core), and Revolution is a complete rewrite so there is no way you can use the old manager with the new core.

Comment: That's sad. Do you know, whether the developers are going to change this in the release?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be so slow..
Make sure you're not using Firefox with Firebug on, while using the manager.   Also, try a different browser.

Revolution's manager does have it's pros and cons, but if you take a quick look at the changelogs until the current RC3, you'll see they are still activly developing the manager interface..